# Django import-export module

Tags: django-import-export

So I have a django project which I run locally via Docker. Recently I've implemented the django-import-export function to export models as an admin to .csv for instance. It all works fine locally but not when deploying the code to my server. I manage my packages with Poetry, and all package versions are the same on Docker and on the server. When entering the django shell on my server I can import the package with 'from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin'. It seems to go wrong in my settings.py. Has anyone encountered this problem? Below are my settings.py etc.

add like this in settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'import_export',
]
```

models.py

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportMixin

@admin.register(Fund)
class FundAdmin(ImportExportMixin, SummernoteModelAdmin):
    ....
```

works locally:
[image]

Comment: Can you verify which versions of django-import-export are being pulled into each image?  The latest version is 2.8.1

Comment: @MatthewHegarty the version is 2.8.0 for both the Docker image and server. Maybe an update to 2.8.1 will work, I will try.

Comment: Obv should be fine if same version on Docker.  However, you could also try the [3.0 beta](https://pypi.org/project/django-import-export/3.0.0b4/) if you are stuck.

Comment: Switching to another version of django-import-export doesn't work unfortunately